# I want to set global directory locations for my CSS and JS locations. How?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, css

I want some sort of  variable to do what `bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' )` does.

Except in a different location!

Is there any way to set global directory locations?

Or am I stuck with copying the old chestnut: `bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' )/assets/styles`

over and over again?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do that.  Create a simple plugin that looks something like this:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: SiteWide Assets Location
Plugin URI: www.mysite.com
Description: Global URI for commonly used CSS and JS files
Version: 1.0
Author: Me
License: None
*/
define( 'SYSTEM_ASSETS', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/somedirectory/' );
```

Then, store your .css and .js files there (or in a subdirectory within that directory), and now in your themes you can simply refer to the constant `SYSTEM_ASSETS` whenever you want that URI location.

Comment: Cool! Thanks  for the response!  Is the constant considered a global variable?  And is that even a big deal in this situation? Is there any built in way?   Like  set_blog_info()?

Comment: It's a constant...sort of a global variable.  You could also create a simple function that returns the same exact string if you don't like constants.  Either way, and neither one is a big deal...this type of thing is done all the time.  Just pick unique names for your constants or functions declared outside a PHP class name scope.